# Using Scala macros from a Jar

Tags: scala, macros

I'm trying to use [Spire](https://github.com/non/spire) in an Eclipse project. I've cloned it from the repo and used sbt package to get a jar (I want to use the latest version as the one available on Maven Central does not have everything I need).

I've created an SBT project and added the jar inside a /lib folder at the root of the project. Now everything works fine, except when I want to use macros from Spire, such as cfor. I use sbt to compile, and get following compilation error message :

> the macro implementation not found: cfor (the most common reason for
>   that is that you cannot use macro implementations in the same
>   compilation run that defines them)

Which is weird, since the macros are contained in a Jar. What am I missing here?

Edit : as requested, a minimal example to show what fails for me https://github.com/Baccata/scala.macros.tests

Comment: Can you post your project to Github? It's hard to say what could be wrong just from the error message.

Comment: https://github.com/Baccata/scala.macros.tests

There you go, I copied a small piece of code from the examples provided by Spire.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to reference both `spire` and `spire-macros` to be able to use macros in Spire.

```
libraryDependencies += "org.spire-math" %% "spire" % "0.7.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.spire-math" %% "spire-macros" % "0.7.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer,

I had just forgotten the macro jar ... the error message being what it is, I didn't think of the obvious.